# Romance between tenured and pre-tenure faculty? Ramifications for disclosure?

Tags: ethics, united-states, tenure-track, non-tenure

I'm an assistant prof in humanities at a small school, just finishing my second year in a new position, and I've developed romantic feelings for a tenured faculty member (Dr X). We are both unmarried, single, and have similar areas of specialization.

Dr X is, unfortunately, currently serving in an administrative position ($$) for the first time this year, a position appointed by our somewhat mercurial dean. Because of this, Dr. X is my immediate supervisor.

We are friends, and I'm quite certain these feelings are reciprocated, but neither of us has made a move because of the rank situation.

What happens if we move forward with this? I'm on track for tenure - publishing well so far, and I have a contract and both internal and external grants for my book manuscript, which will be completed at the end of this summer.

I understand we would have to disclose, but then will Dr. X lose the administrative position if the dean disapproves? Will I potentially damage my tenure case? I've considered going back on the market, but the market is bad, and it seems a lot to risk on an un-tried relationship.

Comment: Surely you should consult the rules of your school, which we do not know.

Comment: HR policies do not specifically prohibit but require disclosure. There is no specific language on faculty-faculty relationships.

Comment: We can't possibly answer questions about people we don't know will respond, like your dean. In a reasonable environment, it would be simple for someone to recuse themselves from decisions about things like tenure, which are typically decided by a committee anyways rather than one individual. The power relationships between department administration and tenure track faculty are nowhere near as imbalanced as the relationships between faculty and students, for example.